# grails controller: access to parameter that has a list of elements

Tags: list, grails, controller

I need to access to items stored in a parameter that represents selected elements in a multiselect. I pass selected items from gsp to controller with the following code into the remoteFunction:

```
params: '\'receiptItemsSelected=\' + jQuery(this).val()'
```

Now, following the code found in discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6464992/accessing-a-list-of-params-in-controller), I use the closure to get each value, but if I perform a multiselect, the size of *receiptItemsSelected* is always 1, but value is, for example, *1,2*. To get values as a list I've done the following in the controller

```
params.list("receiptItemsSelected")
```

but it does not give me two elements if I select two items in the multiselect, but always one element.
The question is: if I select two elements, how can I get each element and use it in the controller? And how can I have that elemnts as Long and not as String?
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're parameters are being passed with string representation of a list, e.g.:

```
http://yoursite.com/?receiptItemsSelected=1,2,3
```

You have to split the value using normal Groovy string manipulation and perform the type conversion yourself:

```
def receiptsAsLongs = params.receiptItemsSelected.split(',')*.toLong()
```

---

If your parameters are passed with the convention of repeated parameters makes a list, e.g.:

```
http://yoursite.com/?receiptItemsSelected=1&receiptItemsSelected=2
```

Then grails can convert this to a list for you using `params.list()`, but you must do the final `String` to `Long` conversion:

```
def receiptsAsLongs = params.list('receiptItemsSelected')*.toLong()
```

Comment: Would this works in the only one item selected case?

Comment: params.list will convert 1 item into a list but won't have a  comma so receiptsAsLongs.each { ...

Answer (score 0):

`params.list()` is intended for multi-valued parameters, i.e. it will work if you have

```
receiptItemsSelected=1&receiptItemsSelected=2
```

You may have more luck using [serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) rather than `val()` to build the request body.

Comment: If I use serialize() rather than val() I obtain only one value at a time, and not all values; plus, the values is like 'value=1', but I need to have only '1' because is the id of an element that I use to do a calculation.